# Nginx config rewrite with PATH_INFO

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I create `.htaccess` file in folder `/var/www/project/`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond $1 !^(statics/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/.]+)|index\.php)$ #ignore folder statics
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/.]+)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L] #Add path_info
</IfModule>

<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
echo 'Path: ', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
```

When I open a url like this `http://localhost/project/profile`, my index.php show this:

```
Path: /profile
```

The problem is that I am unable to do this in Nginx. I tried this:

```
location ~ ^/project/(?!index\.php|statics/|data/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/.]+)$ {
    rewrite  ^(/project/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/.]+)$  $1/index.php/$2 break;
    return 500;
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

    #if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
    #    return 404;
    #}

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

But if open `http://localhost:8000/project/profile` show *404 Not Foud*.

How can I Nginx function identically to .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `last` in `rewrite` and `fastcgi_split_path_info` for fix the `PATH_INFO`, eg.:

> *Note:* use entire path in `rewrite` (like example) and in `location`

```
location ~ ^/project/(?!index\.php/.*|index\.php$|statics/.*|data/.*)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/.]+)$ {
    rewrite ^/project/(?!index\.php/.*|statics/.*|data/.*)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/.]+)$ /project/index.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/project/(?!index\.php).*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;#Fix PATH_INFO

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://winginx.com/en/htaccess

```
# nginx configuration
location / {
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/.]+)$ /index.php/$1 break;
}
}
location ~ *.php {
deny all;
}
location /index.php {
allow all;
}
```

Comment: I had tried, but does not work because it has no accuracy of folders. See my answer. but I appreciate your attempt, thanks.